# Fluent API for having multiple foreign keys from same class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I want to put 3 foreign keys (three separate fields) for same class(Caste)’ primary key (CasteID) in a class(MarriageProfile).

Example:

```
dbo.MarriageProfile
MarriageProfileID   | CasteID | NaniCasteID | DadiCasteID
1           |    1    |    3        |      5
```

How should I add fluent API for this:
Model is:

```
Public class MarriageProfile
{
---
 public int CasteID { get; set; }
        public virtual Caste Caste { get; set; }

        public int NaniCasteID { get; set; }
        public virtual Caste NaniCaste { get; set; }

        public int DadiCasteID { get; set; }
        public virtual Caste DadiCaste { get; set; } 
---
}
public class Caste
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int CasteID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public string Religion { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public string CasteCategory { get; set; }


        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }    

    }
```

I tried it. But generated migration file shows many additional fields.

```
public partial class castechange : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "CasteID", c => c.Int());
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "NaniCasteID", c => c.Int());
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "DadiCasteID", c => c.Int());
                       AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "Caste_CasteID", c => c.Int());
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "Caste_Religion", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "Caste_CasteCategory", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "NaniCaste_CasteID", c => c.Int());
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "NaniCaste_Religion", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "NaniCaste_CasteCategory", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "DadiCaste_CasteID", c => c.Int());
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "DadiCaste_Religion", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
            AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "DadiCaste_CasteCategory", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
-----
}
```

It should contain only first three lines for AddColumn.
Any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the fluent API or data annotations in your entity class. If using data annotations then mark your collection as [ForeignKey("CasteID")] for example.

To use the fluent API you would need to specify it in your DBContext by overriding OnModelCreating such as:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
```

See [Configuring relationships with Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)

You could omit both approaches by using convention. It requires that your foreign key has the same name + Id as your related class - such as Caste, CasteId. The relationship is then inferred by EF.

Here's a link which describes EF conventions more fully:

[Entity Framework Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)